# Drupal production site access issues

Tags: migration, drupal-7, development-environment, production-environment

I am unable to get access to my Drupal 7 website as I migrate it from my dev to prod servers.
The steps I followed are :

1. Take a SQL dump of the database
2. Upload Drupal site into the www/ folder available online
3. Create database on website with the same name
4. Import the SQL dump of the dev database and recreate the tables on the live database.
5. Make changes to settings.php as applies

Now I am not sure what changes to settings.php as applies indicates. However, when I try and access my site at say examplesite.com , I am shown SQLSTATE[280000] Access denied for user 'siteadmin@localhost' using password: YES

siteadmin@localhost is the same guy who acts as administrator on my development website and has the same password.

SO I am not sure why the same login credentials do not work for my dev site.

I also tried the credentials I have to access the control panel of my website but they do not seem to work either

Am I missing a trick here guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Recheck your settings.php twice

If correct, check if you can have a direct access your database with these credentials (via command line or phpmyadmin for example)